# How can I save a simple counter in an iphone application such that I can increment is and the change will be saved between application launches?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

All I want is an integer which everytime my app opens is incremented by one. Is there an easy way to do this? Please help.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to do something like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger counter = [defaults integerForKey:@"counterKey"];
counter++;
[defaults setInteger:counter forKey:@"counterKey"];
```

This also works if the key has never been registered. integerForKey will just return 0, which is actually what we want. However, if you want to be extra-secure, you can check it beforehand. after the second line by something like this:

```
NSInteger counter = 0;
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"counterKey"] != nil)
    counter = [defaults integerForKey:@"counterKey"];
```

Comment: thats so helpful thanks. One more question, is the integers default value zero in the standardUserDefaults?

Comment: The reason I ask is I want the integer to be zero the first time I open it, and to increment it on each subsequent opening.thx

Comment: You would need to register the value 0 before you read in the value using the code above.  Check out the documentation for:
- (void)registerDefaults:(NSDictionary *)dictionary

Comment: If the key does not exist yet integerForKey will return 0. So there is no IMMEDIATE need to register it beforehand, the code will just work.

I adjusted the example such that it shows how to do the check.

Answer (score 1):

Store the integer in `NSUserDefaults`. The documentation is [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

While you *could* use `NSUserDefaults` this way isn't the most elegant solution.

Defaults are a place to keep application *settings* not application *data*. A good guideline is to think of your data item as appearing in your app's settings and whether it is valid there. In your case the number of times the app has been opened is not a user setting; it isn't something that the user will be able to change, is it?

A better way would be to write the data to a plist, which is a simple and fast way of storing application data. Have a look at the instructions [here](http://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-to-plist-file/) for example (there are others available with a quick search), which should get you started.